# Build Java App, Removed dependencies from maven central, on Gitlab Ci

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

My project uses Jaspersoft Reports and I needed to migrate to docker. The build is by gitlab ci, however I get an error when trying to resolve itext dependency. The itext has been removed from the central maven, however I still have the lib in my artifactory repository. I would like to know how I can use my personal repository during the build.

Build stage on gitlab-ci.yml:

```
build_war:
  image: maven:3.8.1-jdk-11
  stage: build_package
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - build
    - exec_docker
  cache:
    paths:
      - .m2/
  variables:
    MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2
  script:
    - mvn dependency:go-offline -B
    - mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-${VERSION}.war
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.mp.mpce</groupId>
    <artifactId>PROJECT_NAME</artifactId>
    <version>DEVEL</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>sajbis-api</name>
    <description>Backend do  sistema de relatórios integrados ao MS Power BI</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jasperreports</id>
            <url>http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jaspersoft-third-party</id>
            <url>http://jaspersoft.artifactoryonline.com/jaspersoft/t‌​hird-party-ce-artifa‌​cts/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.unboundid</groupId>
            <artifactId>unboundid-ldapsdk</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.0</version>
        </dependency>       
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>br.mp.mpce.sajbisapi.SajbisApiApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error print:

[image]